# iPad cannot be restored due to 15 min timeout (recovery mode)

Tags: itunes, ipad, password, restore, virtualbox

I have forgotten my passcode and have tried to restore my iPad(8th 32gb wifi) by [this instruction](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211078). It reboots after 15 minutes and iTunes on my PC says me "Waiting for Ipad..." or "Could not find Ipad". I am using Windows 10(64 bit) by **VirtualBox** which is on Linux(Ubuntu 20.04 lts). I have already downloaded the iOS 14 for iPad. And iTunes does not have to download the iOS. But when it starts to restore it fails due to 15 min timeout. I have tried to update & restore my iPad with [ipsw](https://ipsw.me/) file and without it.

Could you help me to restore my iPad?

And is it possible that it fails due to VirtualBox?